# Expected sub,function or propriety when calling API

Tags: winapi, vb6

I want to store all active window title using EnumWindows API function. But I want to use the function which calls EnumWindows as an callback function too. I want to do this by changing the lParam variable so that the function knows when it has to call EnumWindows and when it is the callback function. The problem is that it gives me an error: "Expected Sub,Function or Propriety.". Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
     ReceiveHwnd 0, 1
End Sub
```

This part of code is in the module:

```
Public Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal Hwnd As Long) As Long 
Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal Hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Public HwndCount As Double, HwndArray() As Long

Public Function GetTitle(Hwnd As Long) As String
     Dim Lenght As Long
     Dim TempValue As String

     Lenght = GetWindowTextLength(Hwnd) + 1
     TempValue = Space$(Lenght)
     GetWindowText Hwnd, TempValue, Lenght

     GetTitle = Mid(TempValue, 1, Lenght - 1)
End Function


Public Function ReceiveHwnd(ByVal Hwnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
      Static Count As Double


      If lParam = 1 Then
           EnumWindows AddressOf ReceiveHwnd, 0
           Count = 0
      Else
           Count = Count + 1

           ReDim Preserve HwndArray(1 To Count)
           HwndArray(Count) = Hwnd
           ReceiveHwnd = 1

     End If
End Function
```

The error is at this line `EnumWindows AddressOf ReceiveHwnd, 0` from `ReceiveHwnd` function.
Can you tell me where's the problem?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you need to have the callback function in a public class module.  I think the problem may be that you have it in a regular module.  I suggest you do a little research on this.

Comment: Hmmm, calling `EnumWindows` from its callback func....looks like bad design to me.